# Writing an Application that just Presses a Button in another App

Tags: android, root

Is there anyway to write a Simple Android Application that Presses a Button in another Android Application? My device is rooted

Answer (score 0):

You can't have your apps push a button on another app. That would be a giantic security leak.

However, the other app might have options on how to call it. It will depend on that other app. You would call the other app with an Intent, then use `putExtra` to provide extra parameters.

But it is very easy if you know the package name, just call the below method in your button onClick.

```
/** Open another app.
     * @param context current Context, like Activity, App, or Service
     * @param packageName the full package name of the app to open
     * @return true if likely successful, false if unsuccessful
     */
    public static boolean openApp(Context context, String packageName) {
        PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
        try {
            Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            if (i == null) {
                return false;
                //throw new ActivityNotFoundException();
            }
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            context.startActivity(i);
            return true;
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```